# How can I select this button?

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am using Selenium to automate the checkout process of a website and can not figure out how to select this certain element properly. So far I have tried all of the following with no luck:

```
//no such element
driver.findElement(By.id("Something here")).click();
//no such element
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="add-remove-buttons"]/input")).click();
//no such element
driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).click();
```

It seems like the closest I've gotten is with:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("button")).click();
```

Using this gives me an error saying the button is not visible. So it looks like I'm heading in the right direction with this, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Here is the HTML source of the button:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="add to cart" class="button">
```

not sure if this plays a part in it but when this button is clicked it changes into a new button. The same location, but different color, text, and functionality.

If you wanted to take a look for yourself here is the website:

http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/accessories/yf89tm27c/e8c56njah?alt=0

and the button I am trying to click is the add to cart button.

Comment: Can you tell where is add-remove-buttton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("commit")));
button.click();
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you this worked! i was wondering if there was any special reason that you first created a new WebElement? or was this just that it was be easily reached again.

Comment: @CodeSoloDolo, I added special wait before click action.